# Reading from csv file in C causing input to not print

Tags: c, string, split, token, strtok

I am trying to read data from a csv file input below:

```
0, 0
5, 0
7, 0
```

This input is supposed to be x and y coordinates where `x= 0` and `y =0` and `x=5` and `y=5` and so on....

**What i have tried**

I am trying to print the numbers and then store each one. I can't store them or print them correctly as I am new to C and I am finding it difficult

**Required output:**

```
x:0      y:0
x:5      y:0
x:7      y:0
```

**This is my code below:**

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>   
#include <curses.h> 
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    FILE* fp = fopen("points.csv", "r");
    if (!fp)
        printf("Can't open file\n");
    else {
        char buffer[1024];
        int row = 0;
        int column = 0;
        int distance;

        while (fgets(buffer,
                    1024, fp)) {
            column = 0;
            row++;
            if (row == 1)
                continue;

            // Splitting the data
            char* value = strtok(buffer, ",");
   
            while (value) {
                // Column 1
                if (column == 0) {
                    printf("x:");
                }
                // Column 2
                if (column == 1) {
                    printf("\ty:");
                }
                printf("%s", value);
                value = strtok(NULL, ", ");
                column++;
            }
        // distance = ((x2-x1) *(x2-x1)) + ((y2-y1) * (y2-y1));
            printf("\n");
        }
        fclose(fp);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you `if (row == 1) continue;` since your input doesn't show a header line?

Comment: You are getting the extra newline because fgets keeps the newline it finds at te end of the line and then you strtok it and it becomes part of the y value.   Remove the newline from the end of the line after fgets returns a string.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I added it because I thought i would get an error if I didn't but I guess it's not needed so i will remove it. Do you know why my other data is not printing  though?

Comment: I removed `printf("\n");`  as you said but I am getting the same output

Comment: Removing the `printf("\n");` from the code does work: https://onlinegdb.com/SDHXiYWCL  But you shouldn't remove the `printf("\n");` - instead you should remove the line feed from the data you read with fgets.  One way to do that is to change the strtok delimiter to `", \r\n"` which  treats `\r` (carriage return) and `\n` (newline) as delimiters - you need both if your CSV file is made on a Windows machine (like copy pasting from this question into a file)  Here is an example with the strtok delimiter change: https://onlinegdb.com/Fzm08pMk6

Comment: Okay I tried that but it didn't change my output. I really don't know where I am going wrong. Should I use `atoi` instead? If not are you able to write an answer so I can learn from my mistakes. Thank you!

Comment: How does your output differ from the output produced by the code at the link I provided?  The link I provided seems to display it the way you were hoping but there must be some difference between what I did and what you did.

Comment: I see it now. Thank you so so much for your help. Much appreciated!

Comment: How would I store each `x` variable and `y` variable though ?

Comment: State machine: you only need to accumulate characters, and bump row/rol on a ',' or '\n' .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your file contains only two columns, you can write it this way using `sscanf()`:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fp = fopen("file", "r");
    if (!fp) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't open file\n");
        return 1;
    }
    
    char line[1024];
    int x, y;
    while (fgets(line, sizeof line, fp)) {
        line[strcspn(line, "\n")] = '\0'; // Replace '\n' read by fgets() by '\0'

        if (sscanf(line, "%d, %d", &x, &y) != 2) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Bad line\n");
        }
        
        printf("x:%d\ty:%d\n", x, y);
    }
    
    fclose(fp);
}
```

Comment: wow! This is a really good answer. I really don't understand the first 2 lines in the while loop before the print like what the significance of`strcspn` and `sscanf` is. Is it possible to add comments of what each line is doing. Thank you again for your answer.

Comment: @DilhanBhagat  strcspn returns the index of the character you pass in.  So `line[strcspn(line, "\n")] = '\0';` finds the newline and uses that to set that index of the line to a string terminator.  The problem is that on Windows boxes where a line ending is `\r\n` it will leave the carriage return at the end of the line.  In this particular code it doesn't even need to be done because sscanf will work even if the newline is there.  You can find the documentation for strcspn at https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcspn

Comment: @DilhanBhagat The sscanf tries to parse the input text by converting the text to integers.  It works as long as the values really are integers. There are advantages to using sscanf to do the heavy lifting for you and there are advantages for using strtok to split the string. For example, what if the line had three numbers on it?  It would work without any errors at all - but with the strtok version you could detect that and print an error. So if you trust the input file to always be right, then sscanf is really good. The documentation for sscanf is at https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf

Comment: @DilhanBhagat if you want to store the x and y up so you can use them later then this would work: https://onlinegdb.com/oEEFEAxt1  If you don't know the maximum size for each line or the number of lines and have to dynamically allocate memory it gets a lot more complicated.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah I assumed that the file contains only two columns. If it's irregular, than `strtok()` is the way to go.